# JavaScript: Limit checkbox checked for a specific Div id

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I need your help to find out how to call an input type=checkbox under sibling divs then to the unable checkbox is the click is greater than 2

This is code

```js
$("#qwrap27491 :checkbox").click(function() {
  if ($("#qwrap27491 :checkbox:checked").length >= 3) {
    $("#qwrap27491 :checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    Alert("Please choose only 2 cases");
  } else {
    $("#qwrap27491 :checkbox").attr("disabled", "");
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="qwrap27491" class="Question">
  <div class="checkboxQuestion">
    <div class="checkboxleft">
      <div class="qNumber" style="display: none;">0.1.15</div><label for="q27491" title="q27491" style="max-width: 385px;">CheckList</label></div>
    <div class="checkboxGroup">
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1568"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">5</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1567"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">4</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1566"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">3</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1565"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">2</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1564"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">1</div></label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: I cannot edit the HTML, this is why I m trying to find the solution via a script.

Thank you
BKC

Comment: id's must be unique in the html

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute should be unique in the same document, try to remove the duplicate once from valid HTML structure.

Try to separate the main selector to prevent the duplication, and you could use the `removeAttr()` function like :

```js
var checkbox_selector = "#qwrap27491 :checkbox";

$(checkbox_selector).click(function() {
  if ($(checkbox_selector + ":checked").length >= 3) {
    $(checkbox_selector + ":not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");

    alert("Please choose only 2 cases");
  } else {
    $(checkbox_selector).removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qwrap27491" class="Question">
  <div class="checkboxQuestion">
    <div class="checkboxleft">
      <div class="qNumber" style="display: none;">0.1.15</div><label for="q27491" title="q27491" style="max-width: 385px;">CheckList</label></div>
    <div class="checkboxGroup">
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1568"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">5</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1567"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">4</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1566"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">3</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1565"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">2</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1564"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">1</div></label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think I have a conflict with the new and old scripts, that I m not allowed to remove, each time I put the min.js the page HTML is broken, Can you please advice ?

Comment: click `F12` to check if there's an error in the browser console.

Comment: Hi @Zakaria, No error in Browser, seems jquery.min.js have a conflict with an existing jquery-1.8.3.js that I m not allowed to remove, I added jquery.noconflict() with no luck. can you please advice ?

Comment: so don't add `jquery.min.js` and check, you don't have to use two versions

Comment: Don't worry, Since you've already the jquery lib added so the code should work just fine if the code has any conflict or error it should be shown in the browser console... now to make sure your code is reachable you could add something buggy like replacing `removeAttr` by `remoaaaaveAttr` and check the console.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the attribute in `else` part like:

```
$("#qwrap27491 :checkbox:not(:checked)").removeAttr("disabled");
```

```js
$("#qwrap27491 :checkbox").click(function() {
  
  if ($("#qwrap27491 :checkbox:checked").length >= 3) {
    $("#qwrap27491 :checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    alert("Please choose only 2 cases");
  } else {
    $("#qwrap27491 :checkbox:not(:checked)").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="qwrap27491" class="Question">
  <div class="checkboxQuestion">
    <div class="checkboxleft">
      <div class="qNumber" style="display: none;">0.1.15</div><label for="q27491" title="q27491" style="max-width: 385px;">CheckList</label></div>
    <div class="checkboxGroup">
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1568"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">5</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1567"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">4</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1566"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">3</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1565"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">2</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1564"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">1</div></label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mamun, it works on this forum, but each time I add the ajax script it breaks the HMTL design. Can you please help

Comment: @BKChedlia, we can only try to find the solution based on the code you have posted here. If the code works here and not in your actual environment then the issue might be something else.....

Answer (score 0):

As a user I'd expect you would prevent me from being able to make an invalid selection. My solution below will disable all unchecked checkboxes as soon as the maximum number of boxes have been selected.

```js
const
  container = document.getElementById('qwrap27491');

function onCheckboxChanged(event) {
  const
    // Get all the checkboxes inside the container element. querySelectorAll
    // will return a NodeList, convert it to an array so we can use filter 
    // and forEach.
    checkboxes = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')),
    // Filter the checkboxes so we have an array with just the selected checkboxes.
    // From this array we only want to know how many items it contains.
    selectCount = checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked).length;
    
  // Iterate over all the checkboxes.
  checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
    // If the checkbox is selected just skip it.
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      return;
    }
    
    // All other checkboxes should be disabled when there are already
    // 2 checkboxes selected.
    checkbox.disabled = (selectCount === 2);
  });
}

// Add a change listener to the container element if we managed
// to retrieve it from the DOM. Whenever a checkbox contained by
// this element is changed we will receive the change event.
if (container !== null) {
  container.addEventListener('change', onCheckboxChanged);
}
```

```css
label {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="qwrap27491" class="Question">
  <div class="checkboxQuestion">
    <div class="checkboxleft">
      <div class="qNumber" style="display: none;">0.1.15</div><label for="q27491" title="q27491" style="max-width: 385px;">CheckList</label></div>
    <div class="checkboxGroup">
      <div class="button-holder"> 
      <label style="max-width: 385px;">
        <div class="checkboxitem">
          <input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1568">
        </div>
        <div class="checkboxlabel">5</div>
      </label>
    </div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1567"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">4</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1566"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">3</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1565"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">2</div></label></div>
      <div class="button-holder"><label style="max-width: 385px;"><div class="checkboxitem"><input type="checkbox" id="q27491" name="q27491" value="1564"></div><div class="checkboxlabel">1</div></label></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Then you need to go to the DOM twice. Once to get the checked ones and another time to get the unchecked ones.

Comment: You could also store the checkboxes in a variable during initialization. That way you don’t have to go to the DOM at all in the change handler.